# WPF: Textblock as item in ComboBox: how to center the text of Textblock vertically?

Tags: wpf, combobox, vertical-alignment, textblock

I use WPF 4.5, Caliburn Micro 2, VS2013. I use TextBlock as item in ComboBox.

The height of ComboBox is 80.

The height of TextBlock is 50.

The font size of text inside the TextBlock is standard.

My following sample xaml code works but it shows the text not vertically centered in TextBlock. **How to make the text vertically centered with/without changing the height of TextBlock to Auto?** Thank you in advance.

```
<ComboBox Width="150"
          Height="80"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations}"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLocation,
                                 Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Height="50"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Background="Aquamarine"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Address}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TextBlock should not have a height but its container should instead. If you want to set the background color for your TextBlock then wrap your TextBlock in a Border or a Grid and set the height on them instead.

Like

```
<Grid Height="50>
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text....../>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text-Align="center"
or you could use a margin on each of the sides.

Comment: TextBlock's TextAlignment is (cited from MSDN) "Gets or sets a value that indicates the horizontal alignment of text content.". I want to center the text vertically within the TextBlock that has height larger that the text self. Applying margin on TextBlock does affect the TextBlock self and not its content.